# Load and Retarget via bpy (Blender python)

Tags: python

I successfully retargeted a makehuman mesh (mhx) with a bvh file in blender using the python script.

`bpy.ops.mcp.load_and_retarget`

Is there a way to specify the number of frames to be retargeted?
By default, it retargets only 250 frames.

My bvh has 880 animated frames. I edited the default value in props.py from 250 to 880 and it works fine. But this is not an authentic solution.

Could you please suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

According the [manual](http://blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.ops.import_anim.html?highlight=operators#bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh) you can use `bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh` operator to import a `.bvh` file:

> bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh(filepath="", axis_up='Y', axis_forward='-Z',
>   filter_glob="*.bvh", target='ARMATURE', global_scale=1.0,
>   frame_start=1, use_fps_scale=False, use_cyclic=False,
>   rotate_mode='NATIVE')

As you mentioned, next step is to *Retarget*, but it seems `bpy.ops.mcp.load_and_retarget` only works for the length of the current timeline *(250 active frames by default)*.

Unfortunately **there is no parameter to set the length** of the animation and adjust the timeline in both methods. But if you know the length of the imported bvh, you can simply assign the value to [**Scene.frame_end**](http://blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_end#bpy.types.Scene.frame_end) **between the execution of both methods**:

```
scn = bpy.context.scene # get the current scene
# execute bvh operator
scn.frame_end = 777 # set new end frame 
# execute retarget operator
```

To get the length of the *bvh animation* and set the end frame dynamically, find the last keyframe of the imported objects via `actions` or `animation_data`, see this answers: [How to find number of animated frames in a scene via python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27889/how-to-find-number-of-animated-frames-using-blender-python-bpy)

Answer (score 1):

Just struggled with this and the documentation hasn't improved, if anyone's wondering you just need to set:

```
bpy.context.scene.McpEndFrame = <your number of frames>
```

before you call load_and_retarget.