# How to find number of animated frames in a scene via python?

Tags: python, scripting, keyframes

I need to find the number of animated frames after importing a `bvh` file  in blender. `scene.frame_start` and `scene.frame_end` only returns the start and end frames in the timeline.

My `bvh` file has 880 animated frames. How can I set my scene length automatically?

Could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: you want to detect the first and last animation frames of a blender scene (not bvh file ) ?

Comment: yes. (and more interested on the last frame)

Answer (score 15):

If the **duration of the scene is known**, simply use [`bpy.context.scene.frame_end`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75a_release/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=frame_end) and assign a *custom duration value* to it - this will overwrite the current **playback/rendering range**:

```
import bpy

# get the current scene
scn = bpy.context.scene 

# assign new duration value
scn.frame_end = 880
```

---

In order to **adjust the scene duration dynamically (based on the included animations)** you'll need to iterate through all the relevant objects in the scene  and read their keyframes by using either *Animation Data* or *Actions*.

#### Keyframes via Animation Data

Use [`animation_data`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=animation%20data#bpy.types.Object.animation_data) to get the **keyframes** of an object. Following example reads the keyframes of the selected objects and prints the **first and the last keyframe** to the console.

```
import bpy
import math

# get keyframes of object list
def get_keyframes(obj_list):
    keyframes = []
    for obj in obj_list:
        anim = obj.animation_data
        if anim is not None and anim.action is not None:
            for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
                for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
                    x, y = keyframe.co
                    if x not in keyframes:
                        keyframes.append((math.ceil(x)))
    return keyframes

# get all selected objects
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

# check if selection is not empty
if selection:

    # get all frames with assigned keyframes
    keys = get_keyframes(selection)

    # print all keyframes
    print (keys)   

    # print first and last keyframe
    print ("{} {}".format("first keyframe:", keys[0]))
    print ("{} {}".format("last keyframe:", keys[-1]))

else:
    print ('nothing selected')
```

#### Keyframes via Actions

Use `bpy.data.actions` to get a list of **actions** in the scene, but actions are not associated with objects, scenes or nodes. Following example reads the [**frame range**](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Action.html?highlight=frame_range#bpy.types.Action.frame_range) of all F-Curves within the actions of the file and prints the **first and the last keyframe** to the console.

```
import bpy

# check if actions is empty
if bpy.data.actions:

    # get all actions
    action_list = [action.frame_range for action in bpy.data.actions]

    # sort, remove doubles and create a set
    keys = (sorted(set([item for sublist in action_list for item in sublist])))

    # print all keyframes
    print (keys)

    # print first and last keyframe
    print ("{} {}".format("first keyframe:", keys[0]))
    print ("{} {}".format("last keyframe:", keys[-1]))

else:
    print ("no actions")
```

#### Test scene

[image]

**Console Output of both methods:**

```
[1, 5, 7, 18, 21, 30, 47, 49, 67, 69, 75, 84, 100]
first keyframe: 1
last keyframe: 100
```

**Speed comparison**

- *Animation Data* method takes **0.000446319580078125** sec.
- *Action* method takes **0.00011038780212402344** sec.

#### Adjusting the timeline

As mentioned above, in order to set the beginning and end of the scene, you can assign the calculated values to `bpy.context.scene.frame_start` and `bpy.context.scene.frame_end`:

```
# get the current scene
scn = bpy.context.scene 

# assign new starting frame
scn.frame_start = keys[0]

# assign new end frame
scn.frame_end = keys[-1]
```

[image]

#### Final Note

It really depends on what you want to achieve. Using `animation_data` is slower, but using `action.frame_range` can be dangerous, because if you have to delete an object during the process, the actions of the objects remain until the blend file is saved again. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27235/3710

Comment: def get_keyframes(obj_list) will return [1, 20, 12, 12] when frame 12,5 is scale keyframe and subframe.
`return sorted(set(keyframes))` solves wrong order and subframe duplication problems.
In addition removing doubles from list with `set` seems to be 100x faster than not creating them in first place with `if x not in keyframes`.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = bpy.context.object.animation_data.action
frame_start, frame_end = map(int, a.frame_range)
```

Test on my own data:
[image]

Comment: This will just return the first and last keyframe of **one object** (the object in context). The question is: "How to find number of animated frames in a **scene** via python?"

Comment: For many cases, for example CMU bvh database, running above straight after a bvh import, when the rig is active object,  will suffice.   Remembering  to take into account current frame when imported, may shift animation depending on import setting. (Some mocap has a ridiculous framerate, good idea to use the settings to add approx one kf per frame)   Also of opinion that starting actions at 0 or 1 is the go, and lay them down with NLA for delayed start etc.

Answer (score 1):

This will output the first, last frames and duration for the whole scene :

```
import bpy

first_frame = 9999
last_frame = -9999
for action in bpy.data.actions :
        if  action.frame_range[1] > last_frame :
            last_frame = action.frame_range[1]
        if action.frame_range[0] < first_frame :
            first_frame = action.frame_range[0]

print ("first frame : ",first_frame, "\nlast frame : ", last_frame,"\nduration : ",last_frame-first_frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know what you are looking for (ie: only one item on stage, and you know the actions are keyframes)
bpy.context.selected_objects[0].animation_data.action.frame_range[1]