# Location keyframes shift (move) by script

Tags: python, keyframes

I'd like write a script.
There is an object with several keyframes. (example in 1,50,100,120 frames)
I need an index and a shifting factor (let it index=2 and shift=30 frame)

The script need to stretch (or move) the keyframe after the index with shift factor.
So when the script finished then the keyframe positions will be (in this case) 1,80,130,150) 
I dig the blender API and I wrote some scripts already but I don't know what can I do.
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome Gabor :) If the link above doesn't solve your issue, please edit your question, add your code or feel free to comment here to get a specific answer. To access the keyframes, see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27889/how-to-find-number-of-animated-frames-using-blender-python-bpy/27946#27946. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!

Comment: Yes it is specific question because no misunderstanding. But I worked out a solution.