# How does `bpy.types.Action.frame_range` work?

Tags: python, scripting

From [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27889/how-to-find-number-of-animated-frames-in-a-scene-via-python) question I learned about using `frame_range` to get start/end frames from actions.

Using it in a custom script I came across some behaviour that I can't explain, I have two actions, one with a single frame, the other with 8, outputting their `frame_range` results in:

```
Idle: <Vector (0.0000, 1.0000)>
Walk: <Vector (0.0000, 7.0000)>
```

The first range is exclusive and the second one is inclusive. All the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.75/bpy.types.Action.html) say is

> **frame_range**
>
> The final frame range of all F-Curves within this action
>      Type:  float array of 2 items in [-inf, inf], default (0.0, 0.0), (readonly)

I'm confused, how should I interpret the results of `frame_range`?

Comment: My guess is that `Action.frame_range` when used elsewhere needs a length, for fcurve modifiers the NLA., hence single frame actions are given the length of 1, by adding one to start frame as end frame,  by default.